# What is the thrust way to expand a sparse-style matrix?

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

Basically, I have a "sparse style" data set, with

```
thrust::device_vector<int> indexes(smallsize);
thrust::device_vector<float> values(smallsize);
```

I'd like to expand this into a single

```
thrust::device_vector<float> expanded(fullsize);
```

I know how to do this with kernels:

```
template <typename T>
__global__ void AssignByIndex
    (
    T* inval,
    T* outval,
    size_t* keys,
    int Ilength
    )
{
    int index = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    if (index < Ilength)
    {
        const size_t key = keys[index];//cross access,slow
        outval[key]=inval[index];
    }
};
```

But 1) this feels like something that thrust can do easily and 2) this doesn't allow me to use fancy iterators. I think I'm just using an incorrect term in my search or am just simply not being creative enough.

Comment: This just sounds like a typical scatter operation.

Comment: @talonmies dude, that was totally the missing keyword. If you put it in answers I'll mark it as such.

Comment: also, [cusp](http://code.google.com/p/cusp-library/) is built on top of thrust and has many useful built in functions for handling sparse matrices, including conversions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a typical scatter operation. Thrust has a [scatter function](http://thrust.github.io/doc/group__scattering.html) that lets you do something like this:

```
thrust::scatter(values.begin(), values.end(), indexes.begin(), expanded.begin());
```

This will scatter `values` into the indices of `expanded`.